# Variable inside of variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, I'm trying to write a batch file that will take my input, slot it into a template that I've created, and put that into a text file.

```
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"

set /p VarOne=Example

echo ** %VarOne% ** > %Output%\%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt
```

This works fine, but if I do it like this, I get an access denied error:

```
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"
set FNAME="%Output%\%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt"

set /p VarOne=Example

echo ** %VarOne% ** > %FNAME%
```

I'm pretty inexperienced so, forgive me if its obvious.

Comment: No error on my system - Windows 10 - what version are you running?

Comment: Don't assign double quotes to your variables.  Only use the double quotes when you are using the variable.  Remove the quotes from the output and FNAME variables.  Then your last line should be `echo ** %VarOne% ** > "%FNAME%"`

Answer (score 3):

Don't assign double quotes to your variables but do use them to quote the `SET` statement as a best practice to protect special characters.

```
set "Output=%USERPROFILE%\desktop"
set "FNAME=%Output%\%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt"

set /p VarOne=Example

echo ** %VarOne% ** >"%FNAME%"
```